# Does the resistance of a curved rod to compression depend on the number of curves?

Tags: biophysics, continuum-mechanics

In *The Physiology of the Joints* by Kapandji, he provides a diagram on page 21

[image]

He does not formally define the concept of "resistance" but just creates this variable $R$ and claims that, if $n$ is the number of curves,

$$R = n^2 +1$$

[image]

He also references an equation called "Delmas Index"

$$DI = \frac{\text{length of vertebral column from tip to tip with curves}}{\text{length of vertebral column from tip to tip fully extended}} \times 100$$

Unfortunately, he provides no citation for any of this. Upon Googling both of these a fair amount, I have sadly found other physiology textbooks reference **only** this book. There doesn't seem to be any actual scientific analysis given.

My question is,

Does an actual quadratic relationship exist between the curves and the resistance of the rod to compression? If so, what is the real equation used in fields like continuum mechanics?

Comment: Delmas Index is just a definition, a measure of the curvature of the spine. It does not seem to be related to $R=N^2+1$. As you say, there does not seem to be any scientific basis for this equation.

Comment: Updated it. He gives no evidence

Comment: Thanks. Is Fig. 11 the diagram which you have reproduced? Are there no references in notes or the bibliography which relate to the claim "Engineers have shown..."?

Comment: No, no references are given

Comment: It might be worthwhile to re-post your question in Engineering SE.